# Apex Data loading from CSV file - Table lookup issue

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

This issue is related to Apex Data loading from CSV file using table lookup(Apex - 5.1)

I created a Data loading wizard for table: "dept_notes"(data should be inserted to this table), before inserting I wanted to have a Table lookup(which actually picks the dept_id column from another table: "depart_details" ) which gets the dept_name from the CSV file I provide and get the respective dept_id and insert into the table.

My CSV file has the below details:

DEPT_NAME, DETAILS,CREATED_BY,DATE,
ENGG,TEST NOTES DETAILS,1213,01-JAN-2018,
BIO,TEST NOTES DETAILS BIO,1213,01-FEB-2018,
COMP,TEST NOTES DETAILS COMP,1213,01-MAR-2018,

And my dept_notes table has the below columns:
DEPT_ID, DETAILS,CREATED_BY,DATE

I have provided the table lookup values correctly mapping the Upload and Return column. I am thrown with the error message

Error during rendering of region "Data / Table Mapping".
ORA-01403: no data found Technical Info (only visible for developers) 
is_internal_error: true 
apex_error_code: APEX.REGION.UNHANDLED_ERROR 
ora_sqlcode: 100 ora_sqlerrm:
ORA-01403: no data found component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES 
component.id: 89498000000029 
component.name: Data / Table Mapping error_backtrace: ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DISP_PAGE_PLUGS", line 997

Any pointers, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Enable debugging and see what's going on.

Comment: A quick question, DEPT_ID is fetched from another table by mapping the dept_name from the CSV, do my CSV file should contain a column named DEPT_ID (mark it with blank column values).. ?

Comment: I think not. Try to test it: if DEPT_ID is a NOT NULL column, shorten the CSV file so that it contains only a single row with a 100% correct DEPT_NAME, so that mapping *must* work. If loading goes OK, then there's a possibility that CSV file contains invalid DEPT_NAME values (which can't be mapped to their DEPT_ID). **Or**, change DEPT_ID so that it allows nulls and run the loading process for the whole CSV file. Once it is done, check which rows have empty DEPT_ID columns and compare them with CSV file, in order to see which DEPT_NAMEs were incorrectly written.

Comment: sound's good.. will try it. thank you.